# Парсить изображения партиями

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток.**
Делаю парсинг изображений, дело в том что целевой сервер отдает только по 60 - 70 изображений. 
Как обойти это ограничение или как можно правильно организовать проверку, если файлы уже были скачаны то пропустить их и парсить следующие которых нет?
**Мой код:**

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/dir/";
foreach ($arrFilterOffer["image"] AS $key => $url) {
  $name = basename($url);
    $newfile = $directory . $name;
    if (copy($url, $newfile)) {
    echo "Successfuly downloaded: " . $url;

    } else {
    echo "Download failed for " . $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: считать название уже закаченых файлов сперва, потом сделать условие, если в массиве есть совпадения то продолжаем дальше, если нет закачиваем

Comment: @Bloom, имеете ввиду так: Сначала opendir, далее readdir считаем имена файлов, далее делаю проверку $file не равно $name то запускаю copy($url, $newfile), так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(is_file($new_file)){
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо указать, что это помогает только второе условие, а вот как парсить в условиях "сервер ограничивает 60-70 файлов" - ничего не сказано (задержки между скачиваниями, использование прокси в несколько потоков и т.п.) Вообще, старайтесь не просто приводить код, но и пояснять его: не всем понятно, особенно новичкам.

Comment: там просто не ясно "сервер ограничивает 60-70 файлов" - пагинация с 60-70 ф-лов на стр, или время выполнения скрипта закончилось, потому не написал ничего по первому условию

Comment: В таких ситуациях обычно уточняют в комментариях под вопросах, а не пишут ответ на непонятный вопрос. Вы новенький, возможно просто не знали, но рекомендую в будущем просто не терять время на написание малополезных ответов.

Comment: @ Ivan Matthews, я точно не знаю причину такого ограничения. Данный сервер находится в другой стране, а моя задача спарсить у него изображения. Я пробовал несколько методов, такие как copy(), file_get_contents, и т.д. но все они скачивают по 60 - 70 файлов, вот по этому я думаю что это сервер как то ограничивает отдачу файлов. Не знаю, как то так... Если что я могу комунить из вас дать xml файл откуда я беру ссылки на image, можете тоже попробовать спарсить. Будет понятней.

Comment: можно и файл, если в логах ошибок сервера нету записей на время работы парсера. скорей всего время выполнения скрипта закончилось https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @ Ivan Matthews, в самом низу вопроса, я вставил ссылку на файл.